# Cycle where numeber are entered and where none is repeate

Tags: python

I have to make a program where numbers are entered. where none of the elements is repeated. The loop ends when 999 is entered, and YOU MUST NOT USE THE LIST. When you ENTER 0 it separates elements by group, indicates the number of elements and indicates the smallest element.

How do I make sure that no element is repeated without using a list?

```
group=0
element=0
n=int(input("Number= "))
minor=9999999

while n != 999:
          
    if n == 0:
        group+=1
        print ("group= ", group , " ," , "number of element", element, "," , "Minor element= ", minor)
        element= 0
        minor=999999
    else:
        element+=1
        for i in range (element):
                 if n < minor:
                     minor = n
    n=int(input("Number= "))
    
 
group+=1
print ("group= ", group , " ," , "Number of element", element, "," , "minor element= ", minor)
print("------------------")
print("Numbers of groups= ", group)
print("end...........")
```

Comment: why don't you want to use a list?

Comment: because the teacher does not allow me to use lists in this exercise.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I don't think we can properly help you with this here. You should probably talk to your teacher in order to understand the reason for this restriction, and to find out what other workarounds are (acceptable/intended). ["Guessing the Teacher's Password"](https://www.readthesequences.com/Guessing-The-Teachers-Password) is not a fun game, even less so when it's on someone else's behalf.

Answer (score 0):

if you really don't want to use a list, the best thing i can think of is writing to a file and reading that file after every number input
i THINK this might work

```
group=0
element=0
n=int(input("Number= "))
f = open('numbers.txt', 'a')
f.write(f'{n}\n')
f.close()
minor=9999999

while n != 999:
          
    if n == 0:
        group+=1
        print ("group= ", group , " ," , "number of element", element, "," , "Minor element= ", minor)
        element= 0
        minor=999999
    else:
        element+=1
        for i in range (element):
                 if n < minor:
                     minor = n

    while True:
      print(open('numbers.txt', 'r').read().splitlines())
      n=int(input("Number= "))
      if n not in [int(x.strip('\n')) for x in open('numbers.txt', 'r').readlines()]:
        f = open('numbers.txt', 'a')
        f.write(f'{n}\n')
        f.close()
        break
    
 
group+=1
print ("group= ", group , " ," , "Number of element", element, "," , "minor element= ", minor)
print("------------------")
print("Numbers of groups= ", group)
print("end...........")
```

I’m aware I still use a list, but I’m not defining it as a variable so I’m sure it doesn’t count